# How is rails prefixing global. to asset scripts in my vendor folder?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, loadimage

I'm trying to use https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image with my Rails 4.2 application and I'm seeing behavior that I cannot explain. The original javascript that I'm putting in my vendor folder will have a line like

`var useCanvas = img.getContext || (loadImage.hasCanvasOption(options) && canvas.getContext)`

that when I view it in the Chrome debugger shows as

`var useCanvas = img.getContext || (loadImage.requiresCanvas(options) && !!loadImage.global.HTMLCanvasElement)`

I didn't find any reference in the asset pipeline documentation that mentions creating a global variable like that. It is probably a simple feature that I'm missing somewhere.